# Drush error when running dmu-analyze to update drupal modules

Tags: drush

I'm using `drupal module upgrader` with drush to update the modules which are drupal 7 compatible at the moment. I'm getting this error when I try running `drush dmu-analyze MODULE_NAME`

[image]

I can't seem to find a solution on the net to fix this issue. I have tried re-installing the module or drush. Even when I type `drush status` I'm also getting this error.

Comment: In future please include error messages as text rather than screenshots, it makes them easier to search. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the modules in your installation is incorrectly using references to services without quoting them.

e.g.

```
[@container.namespaces]
```

instead of the valid:

```
['@container.namespaces']
```

The error message doesn't provide enough details to be able to identify which module is causing the problem. It's going to be a contrib/custom one, though, so check the .services.yml file for the extra modules you have installed and you should find the culprit. It's likely to be under a service whose name begins with `plugin.manager.`.